# Converting two component product to four component notation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, dirac-equation, spinors, dirac-matrices

Consider the product of two left Weyl spinors in the notation commonly found in supersymmetry, 
\begin{equation} 
\chi ^\alpha\eta_\alpha = \chi ^\alpha \epsilon _{ \alpha \beta }  \eta ^\beta 
\end{equation} 
This is equal to,
\begin{equation} 
\left( \begin{array}{c} 
\chi ^\alpha  \\  
0 
\end{array} \right) ^T\left( \begin{array}{cc} 
\epsilon _{ \alpha \beta }  & 0 \\  
0 & \epsilon ^{ \dot{\alpha} \dot{\beta} }
\end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{c} 
\eta ^\beta  \\  
0 
\end{array} \right) = \bar{\eta} _L ^\ast \gamma _0 C \chi _L 
\end{equation} 
where I have used some common spinor identites and defined, $ \eta _L \equiv P _L \eta, \chi _L \equiv P _L \chi  $ ($\eta $ and $ \chi$ are now four component spinors). I also use the defintion, $C \equiv i \gamma_0 \gamma _2 $. While I don't think anything is particularly wrong with this derivation, I have never seen a term like this in normal quantum field theory. It there a simpler way to reformulate this to correspond to common expression for such mass terms or is my uncomfort with this term due to my ignorance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just realize that you can form ordinary Dirac spinors from 2-spinors by using charge conjugation, $i\sigma_2\eta^*$, that gives a right- handed field that can fit in the right-handed slot (forming a 4 component Majorana field)
$$
\Psi_1=\left(\begin{array}{c}\eta \\ i\sigma_2\eta^*\end{array}\right)
$$
And analogous for $\Psi_2$ in terms of $\chi$. Then you just look at the 'mass terms' $\bar\Psi_1 \Psi_2$ to get your term (well in fact you need to insert also a $P_L$). I think the textbook by Ramond shows this kind of things.

Actually, if you add also the hermitian conjugate to your expression, you can even fit all in a single Dirac spinor
$$
\Psi=\left(\begin{array}{c}\eta \\ i\sigma_2\chi^*\end{array}\right)
$$
and look at $\bar{\Psi}\Psi$.

Answer (score 0):

Following this [ref](http://arxiv.org/abs/0812.1594), one sees that, in some basis where the current is diagonal ($3.2.16$), then a term like $\chi \eta$ is just a part of the mass term ($3.2.17$).

Comment: yes, it is exactly the last part of my answer where I say that it's a part of $\bar{\Psi}\Psi$.